# Database get uid for menu creator

Tags: users, database

I just want to get the user information who create a new menu item under menu section.  I am not able to get any entry in database regarding the menu creator (UID). There is a entry in {menu_links} table, but in this table or any other table there is no UID linked.

Comment: Drupal doesn't store that information, you'll need to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module and use the hook `hook_menu_link_insert`. Get the active user with `global $user;` and save the user + link id in a separate table.

Comment: Thanks huelfe, But my problem is to get already saved information. Is there any table in database which save this. or any log where i can found this, as I want to fetch a specific menu entry which was entered by some content editor.

Comment: No, there is no table where you can find information like this. You have to create a custom module for this to provide this feature.